# reading a file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am trying to read a file and display it contents on browser.

I have this code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var fname ;
        if(navigator.appName.search('Microsoft')>-1) { fname = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'); }
        else { fname = new XMLHttpRequest(); }

        function read(filename) {
            fname.open('get', filename, true);
            fname.onreadystatechange= steady;
            fname.send(null);
        }

        function steady() {
            if(fname.readyState==4) {
                var el = document.getElementById('read_file');
                el.innerHTML = fname.responseText;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

But the output on I get is :

```
x   y 5 90 25   30 45   50 65   55 85   25
```

Whereas the data is in format:

```
 x    y
 5    90
 25   30   
 45   50   
 65   55 
 85   25
```

Two questions:

1) How do i display it in the format as above

2) As of now, this happens when I click on a button.. is there any way I can automatically read from this given file rather than clicking on a button

SO this is how my html code looks like

```
<input type="button" value="load file"  onclick="read('data.tsv')">
```

I want to get rid of this "onclick" and just read the file

THanks

Comment: What kind of element is `read_file`? Change it to `<textarea>` or `<pre>`.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's the output you get?  Or is that perhaps the output you see in the browser window after it treats the output like unstyled HTML?  If you're displaying this in HTML, you're going to need to format it as such.  HTML otherwise ignores whitespace, treating all whitespace (multiple spaces, returns, etc.) as a single space character.  You can perhaps wrap it in a `<pre>` tag, or manually add `&nbsp;` codes and `<br />` tags.

Comment: @bfavarretto
<div id="read_file"></div>

Comment: About the onclick part: just call `read('data.tsv')` at the end of your current js code. You probably should put that js block right before `</body>` to make sure the reference to `read_file` will exist when it runs.

Comment: One more thing: instead of sniffing the browser with `if(navigator.appName.search('Microsoft')>-1)`, check for the feature with `if(!window.XMLHttpRequest)`

Comment: @bfavaretto :) thanks for another tip. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the button, just add the call to the end of your JavaScript:

```
    // ...

    read('data.tsv');
</script>
```

There are a couple of ways to display the data as you find it in the file.

The first is to wrap it in an element that preserves white-space...

```
el.innerHTML = '<pre>' + fname.responseText + '</pre>';
```

Or you could replace all the line breaks and tabs / spaces with HTML, for example a line break could be converted into a `<br>` tag and a space could be replaced with a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`.

You could even split it by line-breaks and white-space in order to display it in a table, which would be the correct way of displaying the type of information you have.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I display it in the format as above?

Make sure the element you insert the content into is using `white-space: pre` for styling, otherwise spaces will be condensed. Also, be aware that special characters such as `<`, `>`, `"`, and `&` will need to be escaped for use with `innerHTML`. Typically `<pre>` elements are used when spacing must be preserved.

> As of now, this happens when I click on a button.. is there any way I can automatically read from this given file rather than clicking on a button

If the `<script>` is executed after the `#read_file` element, you could simply call the function:

```
read('data.tsv');
```

If not, you could set an `onload` event handler that would execute when the page has finished loading:

```
window.onload = function () {
    read('data.tsv');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you must replace **< br>** instead of  newline.in browser newline not show

Answer (score 1):

about the format you should use the `<pre>` tag, so the original format will be preserved, more details here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

and to run without user intervention, use `<body onload="read('data.tsv')">`

have fun !